# The php exec function didn't return any output when using it with libreoffice

Tags: php, libreoffice

I am trying to read some Docx and Excel File in my php code using the Libreoffice as the following

```
try {
    $libreoffice = $_SESSION['PATH_OOFFICE'];
    $command = '/usr/bin/libreoffice6.1 -env:UserInstallation=file:///var/www/aalyan/html/trunk/backend/tmp//soffice_profile_us --cat pdf/word.docx 2>&1';
    //$command = 'ls 2>&1';
    exec($command, $exec_output,$ret);
    $output_text = implode(' ', $exec_output);
    $is_readable = strpos($output_text,'Error: source file could not be loaded');

        if ($is_readable === false) {
        unlink($documentfullpath);
        return true;
     } else {
         return false;
     }
    } catch (Exception $ex) {
     return false;
    }
```

when the code on the exce statment he goes and did't back if I have wait for more than 5 min but nothing happining

and when I change the command with just `ls` it works and if I run the first command direct in the shell it works without problems

anyone has any idea on this

Comment: Is the `pdf/` dir writable by the webserver? Also, I don't know libreoffice but why the `///` and `//` in the command?

Comment: yes it is. I used to upload the files to this directory

Comment: `exec` waits until the command exits. It seems you are starting libreoffice but it never closes, so exec won't finish

Comment: Also I can't find any documentation on the `--cat` argument

Comment: This might help: https://askubuntu.com/a/546771/252243